# using npm link with web3

Tags: npm, web3js, lerna, npm-link

I'm trying to patch one of the web3 packages and use the patched version in my node script. I'm confused about what to use in the `npm link` program: `web3` or `web3.js`.

Here's what I did:

1. Cloned the web3 repo.
2. Executed `npm bootstrap` (which linked web3 subpackages).
3. Ran `npm link` (which put a link to the `web3.js` folder into my global modules folder).
4. Created a project named `web3test` and ran `npm install web3` for it.

Now I don't know how to link my project to the local copy of web3. If I run `npm link web3`, it puts a `web3` folder in the global modules directory, which is not the same as my `web3.js` repository. But my project is supposed to use `web3`, not `web3.js`, so it doesn't make sense to link to `web3.js`.

I'm on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that `web` is actually a package within `web3.js`. So I went into the `\web3.js\packages\web3` directory and executed `npm link` from there. Of course, I had to also run `npm build` for the main package so that all web3 packages were built.